# Discrete math: What is the difference between false and inverse in conditional statemensts?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let's say there is this conditional statement:

If I am in Paris, then I am in France.

So, p = 'I am in Paris', and q = 'I am in France'

I do not understand when p and q are false, how would that translate to?

Would it not be the same as inverse of conditional statement?

I would be grateful if you guide me on my misinterpretation.

Comment: Please explain your question a little further. I didn' t get it.

Comment: So, if p and q are false, then the conditional would be "If I am not in Paris, then I am not in France." This is seen as true in the end, if done by a truth table. However, the inverse of a conditional statement, it's the same sentence right? Would the inverse be "I am not in Paris, then I am not in France" as well?

Answer (score 0):

Note: for the following we shall assume that "Paris" refers exclusively to the Capital of France rather than [any of the many other places named Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(disambiguation)).

The Statement is: "If I am in Paris, then I am in France."   Given the above, this is definitely true.
$$p\to q$$

The Inverse of this is: "If I am not in Paris, then I am not in France."   This is not necessarily true, as I may be in Lyon, which is also in France.
$$\neg p\to\neg q$$
The Converse of the statement is: "If I am in France, then I am in Paris."   This is also not necessarily true, for the same reason.
$$q\to p$$
However, the Contrapositive of the statement is: "If I am not in France, then I am not in Paris."   This holds true (given our assumption).
$$\neg q\to \neg p$$
   The Contrapositive of a statement is equivalent to the statement.
$$\neg q\to \neg p \quad\iff\quad p\to q$$

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think in different terms:
It's much simpler to use *if p then q*.
if condition one is met than move on to condition two.
this is a capacitive decision unrelated to the outcome.
*if p then q* does not represent an equation.